# Can't iterate over list from a class

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a "Spell Checker" problem.

I have already created a list that holds the dictionary.

Now I'm trying to see if `word` is in the list.

I'm new to using classes with Python so I am probably missing something tiny.

Recent error has been `"TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"`

Here is an excerpt of code.

```
class SpellChecker():

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.__infile = open(file_name,'r')
        self.word_list = []
        self.temp = self.__infile.readline().strip("\n")
        while self.temp != "":
            self.word_list.append(self.temp)
            self.temp = self.__infile.readline().strip("\n")
        self.__infile.close()

    def spellcheck_word(self, word):
        self.word = word.strip(string.punctuation).lower()
        self.list = self.word_list
        for i in range(self.list):
            if self.word == self.list[i]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
def main():
    test = SpellChecker("dictionary.txt")
    print(test.spellcheck_word("apple"))
```

Comment: It's not related to your issue with iterating, but you probably don't want to be creating attributes like `self.word` and `self.temp` which you only need briefly. Even in a method, you can use regular variables like `word` or `temp`. Local variables will go out of scope when the function ends, but that's not a problem if their value is not useful any more!

Comment: Just to summarize, the error you're getting is because `range` expects an integer (the size of the list) and you have `self.list` which is a list. As @JonathonReinhart pointed out, you should use `len(self.list)` instead. But the more "Pythonic" way is as @juanchopanza wrote: `for i in self.list:` and then you would compare `self.word == i`. Even better, use his other suggestion, just checking if the word is inside the list (as in the return statement)

Answer (score 5):

This is how you would iterate over a list:

```
for wrd in self.list:
```

and this is a simpler way to do what I think you are trying to do. Note that it doesn't require an explicit loop:

```
def spellcheck_word(self, word):
    self.word = word.strip(string.punctuation).lower()
    return self.word in self.word_list
```

`range` is a built-in function that creates a list (in python 2) and an iterable in python 3. If in doubt, use the built-in `help`:

```
>>> help(range)
```

[Python 2 range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

[Python 3 range](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range)